# Convert datatypes in Access Insert

Tags: ms-access, vba

Ok here is my problem. I have a csv file that is created out of my control that has a data for different groupings on the same file. The first seven lines are table headers for each group which are different for each group. So first I import this file into Access into a single table. I have since created queries to access the individual groups for data analysis. The problem is that I need to use an expression on one of the fields but since it has to be text in order to import from the spreadsheet because each column contains numbers and characters because of the headers in the top and because sometimes the data is not in the correct column and needs to be massaged. So what I want to do is insert each group into their own table but I want to convert some of the columns to numbers so that my expression will work. I will post the expression that I am having problems with. Thanks.

```
    Sum(IIf([2000 Query].[Field19]=1,IIf([5000 Query].[Field21]>0,-[5000 Query].[Field21],[5000 Query].[Field21]),[5000 Query].[Field21])) AS [ADJ Invoice Total]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDec:

```
IIf(CDec([2000 Query].[Field19])=1 ...
```

It works like so:

```
?cdec(" 20,121.34 ")
20121.34
```

So commas and leading and trailing spaces should be okay.

CDec is available in VBA but not in MS Access queries. In queries, Val will work:

```
IIf(Val([2000 Query].[Field19])=1 ...
```

Or CDbl, which will accept comma thousand separators and leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: Ok I figured out I think. I did a select into to create the initial table to hold data but I excluded the rows with specific phrases that would eliminate the header rows. Then I manually changed the value to number which it accepted. Then I did a normal insert with the same exclusions as above and it converted the data implicitly.

Comment: My only issue now is truncating the table but I'm sure I can find something on the internet.

Comment: Do you mean `DELETE * TableX` ?

Comment: Oh and CDec is not supported by Access anyway. [link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/225931)

Comment: Oops, sorry, it is supported in VBA but not in MS Access queries (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/225931). You can use Val, which is supported in queries, but is not happy with comma thousand separators.

Comment: Well I ended up going with CDbl because it wouldn't carry over decimal places implicitly. This seems to work and I don't expect comma's in the thousands place.